# R's aov() vs STATISTICA and the ChickWeight data

Tags: r, anova

I am still struggling with the transition from STATISTICA/SPSS to R. 
To get a feel for R, I used the ChickWeight data from the R package.
There is one between-chick/subjects factor, `Diet`, and one within-chick/subjects factor. `Time`, which I used to analyze weight.

Using the R manual, I used the `aov()` function:

```
Chicken.anova <- aov(weight ~ (Time * Diet) + Error(Chick/Time) + (Diet), data=ChickWeight)
```

It yielded one set of effects with `Chick` as error term. The effects included the between chick effect `Diet` (as expected) and also within-subjects effects (unexpected); `aov()` also yielded a second set of effects, with the interaction of `Chick` with `Time` as error term.

When I reshaped the data, so that `Time` could be treated as a repeated measure by STATISTICA, and then used the between subjects factor `Diet` and the within-subject factor `Time` to analyze weight, the anova yielded a different (more familiar) effect pattern. The between subjects factor now listed only `Diet` as an effect, with an F value of 7.14, and `Time(DAYS)` and the interaction of `Diet` with `Time` (`Time` with `DAYS`) were listed within subjects. I thought I understood anovas reasonably well, but I am not able to understand the benefit of the `aov()` result over the STATISTICA result. What accounts for the difference? The outcomes of the `aov()` and STATISTICA analyses are shown below.

R code & results

```
####aov() 
summary(Chicken.anova <- aov(weight ~ (Time * Diet)
+    + Error(Chick/Time) + (Diet), data=ChickWeight))

Error: Chick
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
Time       1  89700   89700 12.4668 0.0009853 ***
Diet       3 121337   40446  5.6212 0.0023723 ** 
Time:Diet  1   2482    2482  0.3450 0.5599840    
Residuals 44 316586    7195                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Error: Chick:Time
          Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq  F value    Pr(>F)    
Time       1 1962914 1962914 348.4347 < 2.2e-16 ***
Time:Diet  3   84222   28074   4.9834  0.004464 ** 
Residuals 46  259142    5634                       
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

STATISTICA results

```
        SS  Degr. of    MS  F   p
            Freedom         
Intercept   5567063 1   5567063     1425.22 0.000000
Diet        83716   3   27905       7.144   0.000489
Error       179681  46  3906        
DAYS        1346422 9   149602      259.603 0.000000
DAYS*Diet   76737   27  2842        4.932   0.000000
Error       238578  414 576
```

Comment: A couple of thoughts: Your `aov()` formula is a bit redundant, `weight ~ Time*Diet + Error(Chick/Time)` is equivalent. Note that the design is unbalanced - `xtabs(~ Time+Chick, data=ChickWeight)` shows that chicks `incl <- c(8, 15, 16, 18, 44)` provide incomplete data. Running `summary(aov(weight ~ Time*Diet + Error(Chick/Time), data=ChickWeight, subset=!(Chick %in% incl)))` then causes `Time` only to be tested against the `Chick:Time` SS. Finally, `Time` is not a factor in this dataframe, but shoud be. I don't know how to replicate the Statistica results though.

Comment: Thank you Caracal. I figured out how to replicate the STATISTICA result (see below). However, I do not understand why aov() would compute a main effect of Time and the interaction of Time:Diet with Chicks as error term.